# Is this Hadith about Friday ghusl abrogated?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, jumuah

> Narrated Abu Sa`id Al-Khudri:
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Bath on Friday is compulsory for those who have
> attained the age of puberty."
>
> <sub>[Sahih al-Bukhari 2665](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/52/29)</sub>

Is it abrogated because most scholars don't consider ghusl on Friday obligatory but rather a highly recommended Sunnah?

Comment: I think the topic of this hadith has been discussed on the site before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jummah (Friday) prayer without ghusl](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33192/jummah-friday-prayer-without-ghusl)

Comment: @Medi1Saif Yes, it is discussed here:https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40987/what-does-wajib-mean-in-this-hadith-about-doing-ghusl-in-jumua-friday. Although explicitly speaking, it is talking about the meaning of wajib in this context and my question is whether it is abrogated.

Comment: The point is rather whether the statement of the hadith is interpreted as a constituting *fard* (obligation) or a recommendation. And that is discussed in [When does an order constitute Fard?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/42562/when-does-an-order-constitute-fard?)